# How to maximize space on recycled external HDD?

Tags: partitioning, external-hard-drive

My husband gave me his 4 year old external hard drive, a WD My Passport 0750, 1 TB, to use with my Windows 8 laptop. There is only 29.8 GB worth of free space and it has too many partitions.  How do I fix it so I can use as much of the 1 TB as possible?

I've never had an external hard drive before.  I've been searching for days for the system partitions so I do not erase the software.  Can anyone tell me what system partitions the Passport comes with from the factory, or how to merge the partitions so I can use the space, or how to reset it to the original default configuration?

Comment: Since it's an external drive, backup any data you care about elsewhere, then just delete all partitions via `Start / Run / diskmgmt.msc`, [create a new simple volume](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309170.aspx), format as NTFS and enjoy. No system partitions required on the external HDD.

Answer (score 1):

There is usually no system partition on an external drive. If your husband does not care about the data on the disk, you can get rid of all the partitions. Here is what you do:

Press Start and type **Disk Management** on the start screen. Then you will see what's on the first picture below. Click where the arrow points or on the light blue field with the cog wheel which would skip the next picture. After that you get the second picture below. Click again where the arrow points. Now you are in Disk Management - 3d picture.

Here you right click on a partition and **Delete Volume**. Then you right click again on that partition and **Delete Partition**. Now you should have Unallocated space. You do that for every partition on the disk until the whole disk is unallocated space.

Now you right click on that unallocated space and **create a simple partition**. The Wizard will guide you. If you have any question, post a comment.

PS - Don't be confused by the colors on my pictures. I use a high contrast theme because of my bad eyes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just a plain repartition is a trivial matter. I cannot recommend any specific tools to do this, as I do not know your operating system, but by googling "partition tool" and make sure it's one for your platform, and you should be good (Windows has a built in one, I think it's under disk management).

repartitioning the drive while retaining the data on it makes it harder, and it can be prone to errors. I recommend backing up any data on it that you want to keep, and delete all the partitions on it, and create a new one that fills the entire drive.

If I understood your question correctly, you seem to have misunderstood something about partitioning the drive: You do not need software from the hardware manufacturer to do this - any (decent) partitioning tool will do.

When creating the new partition, you get asked which filesystem to use. This depends a lot, but if you're on windows, NTFS will do. If in doubt, FAT32 or exFAT will be a safe choice as long as you are aware of 4Gb as maximum file size.

Answer (score 0):

The best option to free space if you don't need the data stored on the drive is to simply reformat it. You won't be needing any specific software and can use your OS in order to do that.

Here's an article from our KB that can help you with the steps how to do that:

http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3865/

Hope this helps and best of luck! :)